# suppress warnings on multiple compiler builds

Tags: c++, c, compiler-warnings

Is there a generic suppress warning that i can use?

The problem is that there are times i may build using one compiler version (gcc) and then i have a partner that uses some of the common things but uses a different compiler. So the warning # are different.

The only way i could think of doing was making a macro that was defined in a file that i would pass in some generic value:

```
SUPPRESS_WARNING_BEGIN(NEVER_USED)
//code
SUPPRESS_WARNING_END
```

then the file would have something like:

```
#if COMPILER_A
    NEVER_USED = 245
#endif

#if COMPILER_B
    NEVER_USED = 332
#endif


#define SUPPRESS_WARNING_BEGIN(x) /
     #if COMPILER_A
        //Compiler A suppress warning x
     #endif

     #if COMPILER_B
        //Compiler B suppress warning x
     #endif

#define SUPPRESS_WARNING_END /
     #if COMPILER_A
        // END Compiler A suppress warning
     #endif

     #if COMPILER_B
        // END Compiler A suppress warning
     #endif
```

Don't know if there is an easier way? Also i know ideally we all would just use the same compiler but that is unfortunately not an option. Just trying to find the least complicated way to support something like this and am hoping there is a simpler way then mentioned above.

thanks

Comment: I think the simplest way is writing code that doesn't generate any warnings :-)

Comment: The easiest way to suppress warning would be to disable them when compiling (e.g. drop `-Wall` and friends for gcc). Gcc also allows you to turn of specific warnings via `#pragma`s. But that different compilers warn you about different things could also be an advantage, in that you could *fix your code* for multiple issues and not be too stressed-out about remaining, benign warnings.

Comment: That PP code isn't valid. You can't have `#` inside defines.

Comment: Do not tolerate warnings or artificially remove them, a program should generate `0` warning.

Comment: @sidyll again that is easier said then done. If you decided to include all of openssl are you telling me you have fixed any and all of their warnings? I understand in that case you could just suppress all warnings at the GNUMakefile level but the same idea in some ways applies here.

Additionally would it be better to suppress a few areas of warnings in order to turn on warnings to errors to eliminate all future warnings or to leave as is and hope that time permits to go back and clean all those warnings up. some warnings are freebies while others aren't.

Comment: @honk yes originally i was using pragma but the pragma being used is also specific to the compiler, no generic pragma (that i know of) that can be used across multiple compilers

Comment: @ouah yes the idea is to clean up the freebie warnings and leave others but suppress them in a block in order to be able to then raise warnings to errors sooner than later, then allow to slowly fix those "exceptions" but eliminate the possibility of adding additional warnings

Comment: @ouah: I prefer to have more warnings, also about things which are potentially safe. Things like `-Werror` are the first thing I have to remove after cranking up the warn level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no portable way to do that.  Different compilers do it in different ways (e.g. [`#pragma warning`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), [`#pragma GCC diagnostic`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html), etc.).

The easiest and best thing to do is to write code that does not generate any warnings with at compiler at any warning level.

If your goal is to suppress warnings about unused variables, I recommend using a macro:

```
#define UNUSED(x) ((void)sizeof(x))
...
void some_function(int x, int y)
{
    // No warnings will be generated if x is otherwise unused
    UNUSED(x);
    ....
}
```

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile-time, and the cast to `void` produces no result, so any compiler will optimize the `UNUSED` statement away into nothing but consider the operand to be used.

GCC also has the [`unused` attribute`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html):

```
// No warnings will be generated if x is otherwise unused
int x __attribute__((unused));
```

Comment: Why not simply `((void) (x))` for the definition of `UNUSED`?

Comment: Yes that does make sense. Unfortunately i was using that particular one as an example ideally i would use it for potentially many warnings and not just that specific one.

Comment: @ouah: That works too.  It would make a difference if you passed in an expression with side effects (like calling a function), since the `sizeof` version would not have the side effects, but there's no good reason to ever pass anything besides a variable name.  I wonder if there's a way to make it a compiler error if you expand `UNUSED` with anything other than a variable name...

Comment: @AdamRosenfield I thought it was for that but I had the same reasoning it was not so useful because the purpose of this macro is to be used with a variable name. Plus there are always the rare cases where `sizeof` may evaluate the size expression part of its *expression* operand like in `int n = 0; sizeof *(int (*)[n++]) 0;`